# Building QT Project with MSVC2013?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2013

I am attempting to build some group's project with QT Creator and the only guide I got was that it should be built using MSVC2013. QT's regular kits do not have MSVC 2013 32-bit and 64-bit (I guess they don't go back that far), so I tried to download a legacy version (4.12.2) along with Visual Studio Express 2013 but I can't seem to find where to go from here.

Can someone suggest the cleanest way to build a complete QT project using MSVC2013? Preferably in a way that a VHDL developer would understand!

Comment: You will likely have to build Qt from source using Visual Studio 2013. I am not sure what the maximum version of Qt that will still compile with VS2013. I have built Qt-4.8.7 with VS2013

Comment: I'm seeing that I would need to do this, but after trying to follow some procedures and running into walls, I'm not sure what I'm doing. How did you go about building Qt-4.8.7 with VS2013?

Comment: Did you install perl and python before you ran configure.bat in the source code download? I use the ActiveState versions when I built Qt-4.8.7 with VS2013.

Comment: I did the following (referencing https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git):

Installed Git 2.27 ||
Installed Active Perl 5.28.1.0 (selected to add to PATH) ||
Installed Active Python 3.7.4 ||
Installed DirectX SDK from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6812 ||
Installed Visual Studio Community 2013 ||
Installed Windows 8.1 SDK from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive/ ||
Uninstalled Active Perl 5.28.1.0 Installed Strawberry Perl 5.30.2.1 32-bit

Comment: Went into Git Bash, ran git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qt5.git; cd qt5; git checkout 5.4
Tried to run perl init-repository but it's stating Can't locate Pod/Usage.pm in @INC. My system PATH variable and user PATH variable both contain: C:\Python37 || C:\Python37\DLLs\ || C:\Python37\Scripts || C:\Python37\Tools || C:\Strawberry\c\bin || C:\Strawberry\perl\site\bin || C:\Strawberry\perl\bin in that order at the beginning.

Comment: I just downloaded the source from here: [https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/4.8/4.8.7/](https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/4.8/4.8.7/) either of the  qt-everywhere-opensource-src archives.

Comment: Thank you! When I tried to build that I actually got an error I could trace. There were quotes around one of the values in PATH. 

Sorry for the increasingly boneheaded nature of these questions, but now that I have the source built (to the best of my knowledge), how do I actually run the program to open and build the .pro file I have been given? Does this Qt run the same way as current versions with the IDE GUI and everything? I can't seem to find documentation for a question so basic. I can only run Designer in this standard way.